# can I run apache storm without install python?

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm

I am going to test Apache storm for my personal project.

However I don't want to include python support，

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have python in order to start working with Storm. You can just follow basic tutorial and start playing with it with pure java.

However it does support non jvm based language with is implemented via the ShellBolt class. but that should not be a constraints for learning storm.

Comment: thank you. so if I don't using ShellBolt, it should be fine. let me test and update you later.

Comment: yes just run a simple [word count](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java) topology , and it should work

Comment: Be careful if you want to deploy on a cluster. All scripts for storm are written in python... For a LocalCluster all in java no problems though.

Comment: on a production cluster it expects Python 2.6.6 to be installed